# Call javascript object as function

Tags: javascript

In [Jest testing framework](https://github.com/facebook/jest), there is a `jest.genMockFn()` function that create object which can be called as function and simultaneously accessing it's properties.

```
var mockFn = jest.genMockFn()
mockFn('Hello world!')
mockFn('The world is yours.')
console.log(mockFn.mock.calls) // [["Hello world!"], ["The world is yours."]]
```

When I dump `mockFn` i get:

```
{ [Function]
  _isMockFunction: true,
  mock: 
   { calls: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     instances: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  mockClear: [Function],
  mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
  mockReturnValue: [Function],
  mockImpl: [Function],
  mockImplementation: [Function],
  mockReturnThis: [Function],
  _getMockImplementation: [Function] }
```

I can't figure out how they achieve this. Any ideas? Can you provide code with similar functionality? Thank you.

Comment: A [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) *is* an object, and therefore you can set/get properties on it like any other JavaScript object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of a function is

> [**4.3.24 function**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.24)
>
> member of the Object type that is an instance of the standard built-in
>   `Function` constructor and that may be invoked as a subroutine

So having an object which can be called is not weird. All functions behave like that.

Specifically, this is done using [[Call]], an [internal property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) only defined for some objects.

> Executes code associated with the object. Invoked via a function call
>   expression. [...] Objects that implement this internal method are
>   *callable*.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide an example, please?

Comment: @user2078693 `function f(){ alert('I am callable'); } f.prop='I can have properties'; f instanceof Object === true`

Answer (score 1):

This code may allow you to define a function with attributes

```
var func = function () { };
func.attr = "value";
```